# IDA Pro: Converting structure to decimal

Tags: ida, disassembly, windows

I'm new with IDA pro and have little problem. Right click on some data in `.rdata` brings options in which I can convert, In that window D means decimal B means binary and so on, but I have multiple Ds in which I can convert, and the values in which it can be converted are different, what is the difference between this Ds? Here is the picture

[image: for example]

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly this is the [MakeData](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/453.shtml) command. So it will change the data type that is used to display the values you have.

If you check closely you would notice that from the bottom the pattern is: `byte`, `word`, `dword`, `qword`. Those two at the top are probably the two are some forms of float/real numbers created from the data you're trying to convert.